# Function of difference between variables for each id, then iterate

Tags: r

I would like to make this function and name the new column the same name as the column had before calculating the difference between each period for each id. Therefore I but colnames(df)[i], but it doesn't work? Then I want to run this function over several columns.

```
id <- rep(1:3,each=2)
period <- rep(1:2,3)
q1 <- c(3,2,4,1,8,5)
q2 <- c(4,1,2,1,9,6)
q3 <- c(6,4,6,1,4,2)

df <- data.frame(id, period,q1,q2,q3)
df

id period q1 q2 q3
------------------
1      1  3  4  6
1      2  2  1  4
2      1  4  2  6
2      2  1  1  1
3      1  8  9  4
3      2  5  6  2

test <- function(i){
  d <- df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(colnames(df)[i] = abs(diff(i)))
  return(d)

}

test(3)

num <-list()
quest <- c(4:6)
(for i in 1:length(quest)){
  i <- quest[n]
  num[[n]] <- test(i)
}
```

In the end it should look like:

```
     id q1 q2 q3
     -----------
     1  1  3  2
     2  3  1  5
     3  3  3  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `summarise_at` which can apply a function to multiple column at once.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with('q')), ~sum(abs(diff(.))))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
#     id    q1    q2    q3
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1     3     2
#2     2     3     1     5
#3     3     3     3     2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But in my real dataset the colnames will have no logic, do you have a suggestion how to instead decide which column by the number of the columns?

Comment: Yes, `summarise_at` also accepts column positions but you have to adjust based on number of grouping columns you have. Here as we have only one column, we can use `summarise_at(2:4, ~sum(abs(diff(.))))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- grep('^q\\d+$', names(df), value = TRUE)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(abs(diff(x)))), id, .SDcols = nm1]
```